# Why does dlsym produce different results in cgo than in c?

Tags: c, go, dlopen, cgo, dlsym

I have two implementations of the same behavior that I believe should produce the same results but are instead producing different results. When compiled in Go using `cgo`, I get a different symbol address resolution than when compiled in C. I would like to understand why.

I reduced the problem to a couple of small examples, one in C and one in Go. I tested these in an Ubuntu 18 Docker container running on my Mac laptop.

test.c:

```
// gcc test.c -D_GNU_SOURCE -ldl
// Output: Real: 0x7fd05559d7d0 Current: 0x7fd05559d7d0

#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    void * fd = dlopen("libc.so.6", RTLD_LAZY);
    void * real_sym = dlsym(fd, "accept");
    void * curr_sym = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "accept");
    printf("Real: %p Current: %p\n", real_sym, curr_sym);
    return 0;
}
```

test.go:

```
// go build test.go
// Output: Real: 0x7f264583b7d0 Current: 0x7f2645b1b690
package main

// #cgo CFLAGS: -D_GNU_SOURCE
// #cgo LDFLAGS: -ldl
// #include <dlfcn.h>
import "C"
import "fmt"

func main() {
    fp := C.dlopen(C.CString("libc.so.6"), C.RTLD_LAZY)
    real_sym := C.dlsym(fp, C.CString("accept"))
    curr_sym := C.dlsym(C.RTLD_NEXT, C.CString("accept"))
    fmt.Printf("Real: %p Current: %p\n", real_sym, curr_sym)
}
```

I get the output of `Real: 0x7fd05559d7d0 Current: 0x7fd05559d7d0` when `test.c` gets compiled (`gcc test.c -D_GNU_SOURCE -ldl`). However, when I build `test.go` I see `Real: 0x7f264583b7d0 Current: 0x7f2645b1b690`.

I assume that go is wrapping some symbols itself, but I would like to know exactly what's happening. Thanks!

---

A couple of extra pieces after seeing some of the initial comments. I changed `test.c` as below and then ran in a loop (`while [ 1 ]; do   ./a.out; done`). It's consistently getting equal addresses for me (different each run, though).

```
// gcc test.c -D_GNU_SOURCE -ldl
// Output: Real: 0x7fd05559d7d0 Current: 0x7fd05559d7d0

#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>

    int main() {
    void * fd = dlopen("libc.so.6", RTLD_LAZY);
    void * real_sym = dlsym(fd, "accept");
    void * curr_sym = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "accept");
    if(real_sym != curr_sym) {
        printf("Real: %p Current: %p\n", real_sym, curr_sym);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I also tried a modification of the Go code to check if it had to do with how Go called out to C, but that still did not have the addresses match:

```
// go build dos.go
// Output: Real: 0x7f264583b7d0 Current: 0x7f2645b1b690
package main

// #cgo CFLAGS: -D_GNU_SOURCE
// #cgo LDFLAGS: -ldl
// #include <dlfcn.h>
// #include <stdio.h>
// int doit() {
//     void * fd = dlopen("libc.so.6", RTLD_LAZY);
//     void * real_sym = dlsym(fd, "accept");
//     void * curr_sym = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "accept");
//     printf("Real: %p Current: %p\n", real_sym, curr_sym);
//     return 0;
// }
import "C"

func main() {
    C.doit()
}
```

Another point is that I get the two addresses to match in both the C and Go code if I look for the `malloc` symbol instead of `accept`.

Comment: why would you expect them to be the same? I'll delete this unhelpful comment later if you want but i dont understand the assumption your making.

Comment: The dynamic linker does not necessarily load libraries and individual symbols at the same (virtual) address every time.  I don't presently see any reason to expect that the outputs of the two programs would be the same.

Comment: Do you even get the same results if you run either one program repeatedly?

Comment: Your `dlopen` might have loaded _another_ libc.so.6 which you should avoid. There is a `RTLD_NOLOAD` option for this.Also there is the nightmare called symbol-versioning...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason is that Go links against libpthread, but your C program doesn't. If I add `-lpthread` to the gcc arguments, it prints different pointers too. So, libpthread defines its own `accept` and overrides the libc one (which kind of makes sense).

The way I figured that out is that I inserted a sleep into both programs and then rummaged through `/proc/$pid/maps` to see what the returned pointers reference. That showed that in Go's case, the "current" pointer resides in libpthread. The "real" pointer always references libc.

Answer (score 6):

The symbols aren't loaded into fixed addresses in memory; they go wherever the loader decides to put them.

This is the output of me running your C program multiple times on my machine.

```
govind@Govind-PC:/mnt/c/Temp$ ./dlst
Real: 0x7f4b5f3127d0 Current: 0x7f4b5f26ee30
govind@Govind-PC:/mnt/c/Temp$ ./dlst
Real: 0x7f45727127d0 Current: 0x7f457266ee30
govind@Govind-PC:/mnt/c/Temp$ ./dlst
Real: 0x7fc3373127d0 Current: 0x7fc33726ee30
govind@Govind-PC:/mnt/c/Temp$ ./dlst
Real: 0x7f0e555127d0 Current: 0x7f0e5546ee30
govind@Govind-PC:/mnt/c/Temp$ ./dlst
Real: 0x7f2fdd9127d0 Current: 0x7f2fdd86ee30
govind@Govind-PC:/mnt/c/Temp$ ./dlst
Real: 0x7fec7db127d0 Current: 0x7fec7da6ee30
govind@Govind-PC:/mnt/c/Temp$ ./dlst
Real: 0x7f07de1127d0 Current: 0x7f07de06ee30
govind@Govind-PC:/mnt/c/Temp$
```

See also:

[Address Space Layout Randomization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization)

Comment: My understanding of ASLR is a bit rusty. I'm trying to grok the article. Doesn't ASLR apply to multiple runs of the process and/or the relationship between symbols? In this case, when we have the same symbol being accessed by the same process, isn't it going to have the same address? Obviously not from your testing and my Go code. . . but it appears to sometimes hold.